# How can I create project using INET and LTE library in omnet++5.5.1

Tags: grpc-c++, symbolicc++

I can't add the libraries from makemake I don't have "Add folder" option

I followed this steps
Right click in project from project explorer then use properties then go to makemake then I should click on add folder but I don't have this option